# react navigation props not working after adding react context

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, react-context, forward-reference

i have used react context to use the information of different component however, after adding a context and wrapping it with the current components is blocking the navigation props and stopped displaying header component from the screen.

i have tried almost all the possible solution which i know.
earlier navigation and header was visible.

Navigation:

```
static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => ({
    header: <Header headerTitle="Profile" onPress={() => navigation.goBack()} />
  })


export default withTheme(
  React.forwardRef((props, ref) => (
    <UserContext.Consumer>
      {({ updateUser }) => <UserProfileScreen {...props} updateUser={updateUser} ref={ref} />}
    </UserContext.Consumer>
  ))
)
```

after wrapping a component the static navigationOptions stopped working and in fact header disappeared from the app.

Everything is working fine, i am able to update the user information after react context code but unable to get the information of navigation props.
i expect i can use Header component from the user profile screen and header component to be visible.

Comment: I am also facing the exactly same issue. I have overridden the back button functionality. And it is working. As soon as I wrap with a Context Consumer, The back button's custom behavior that I wrote is not working. Also Navigation header title is not showing after wrapping with context. Did you find any solution? Please share if you have any direction.